# Convert char from fgets to Wchar*

Tags: java, c++, corba, idl

I'm trying to send a "string" from a C++ client to a Java server. On the server-side the username is a `String`. In my IDL it's a `WStringValue`, so I have to send the username as a `WStringValue` from my client. The following code works fine on both sides:

```
const CORBA::WChar* usern = (wchar_t*)L"Chuck Norris";
CORBA::WStringValue* username = new CORBA::WStringValue(usern);
```

But I want to get the user name from the keyboard... Now, my question is how to convert the `char[]` to a `Wchar*`? After my experiments, it seems there is a problem with encoding too..

```
cout << "Please type your Username: " << endl;
fgets(input, MAX_LINE, stdin);
strcpy(username, input);

const CORBA::WChar* usern = (wchar_t*)username;
CORBA::WStringValue* username = new CORBA::WStringValue(usern);
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You may try to do it the following way:

```
std::string str (input);
std::wstring ws;
ws.assign (str.begin(), str.end());
const CORBA::WChar* usern = ws.c_str (); // warning: it will live only while ws lives
```

Comment: I'am such a noob! How do I convert it vice-versa..?! :( From WStringValue* to std::string? Sorry, for that question but I would really appreciate it, if you can help me again...!

Comment: @Simon well, try to do it backwards: `wstring ws (WStringValue); string s; s.assign (ws.begin(), ws.end());`